# SQL SELECT using 3 tables

Tags: sql

3 tables: `Tasks`, `Projects`, `Statuschanges`

The following query works fine:

```
select 
    p.projecttypename, p.projectname,
    t.country, t.taskid,
    sc.username, sc.comment, sc.fromstatus, 
    sc.status as tostatus, sc.status as nextstatus 
from 
    iris_RPROD_CPP_R2.TASKS t,
    iris_RPROD_CPP_R2.Projects p,
    iris_RPROD_CPP_R2.statuschanges sc 
where 
    sc.Incorrectlyrouted= 'True'   
order by 
    statuschangeid
```

but I want same information with count of t.taskid like:

```
select 
    p.projecttypename, p.projectname,
    t.country, count(t.taskid),
    sc.username, sc.comment, 
    sc.fromstatus, sc.status as tostatus, sc.status as nextstatus 
from 
    iris_RPROD_CPP_R2.TASKS t,
    iris_RPROD_CPP_R2.Projects p,
    iris_RPROD_CPP_R2.statuschanges sc 
where 
    sc.Incorrectlyrouted= 'True'   
order by 
    statuschangeid
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Can you please share the schema & relationships between the tables? Also please do not use this old comma separated style of selecting from tables. use Joins. And to start with you can go ahead and read a little about usage of GROUP BY in SQL. You might end up getting it by yourself.

Comment: can you please provide sql fiddle with current and expected output?

Comment: Use group by on remaining columns. 
Before the order by clause, just add `group by p.projecttypename, p.projectname..`

Although, as @AkankshaSingh said, comma separated method of joining table is outdated. So, you should use joins.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: No join conditions? Strange...

Comment: Your use of of the aggregate is invalid SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add count(taskid) and group them as below :

I have added `COUNT(t.taskid) AS Expr1` :

You can also change the `Expr1` with name you would like to give to count of `TaskId` column

```
SELECT        p.projecttypename, p.projectname, t.country, t.taskid, sc.username, 
              sc.comment, sc.fromstatus, sc.status AS tostatus, sc.status AS nextstatus, 
              COUNT(t.taskid) AS Expr1
FROM          TASKS AS t CROSS JOIN
                         Projects AS p CROSS JOIN
                         statuschanges AS sc
WHERE        (sc.Incorrectlyrouted = 'True')
GROUP BY p.projecttypename, p.projectname, t.country, t.taskid, sc.username, sc.comment, 
         sc.fromstatus, sc.status, sc.statuschangeid
ORDER BY sc.statuschangeid
```

Comment: when use this query ,i got below error 
ERROR: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
SQL state: 40001
Detail: User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.